Error while building SPM package with ObjC code
I have objc project https://github.com/facebookincubator/SocketRocket which I forked and adding SPM support. I create Package.swift:
let package = Package(
    name: "SocketRocket",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v12)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "SocketRocket",
            targets: ["SocketRocket"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SocketRocket",
            path: "SocketRocket",
            publicHeadersPath: "."
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SocketRocketTests",
            dependencies: ["SocketRocket"],
            path: "Tests"
        )
    ]
)

There is an umbrella header file inside of project SocketRocket.h:
#import <SocketRocket/NSRunLoop+SRWebSocket.h>
#import <SocketRocket/NSURLRequest+SRWebSocket.h>
#import <SocketRocket/SRSecurityPolicy.h>
#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>

I created a modulemap:
module SocketRocket {
    header "SocketRocket.h"
    export *
}

But there is issue in building package:
Building for debugging...
fatal error: 'SRDelegateController.h' file not found
#import "SRDelegateController.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
I think imports is not applying, every time I run again and again there is different number of compiled files(0, 3, 4, 19):
[0/19] Compiling SRIOConsumerPool.m
I'm expecting to solve my problem.
Project Structure

You need use publicHeadersPath and don't need use modulemap

But I dont have modulemap in the project

UPD same issue with or without modulemap

For SPM with Objective-C file you need to put all header (.h) files in the same folder (eg: include). Look here
